# Creating a scope in Rails 3 based on a has_one :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2

I have the following class

```
class item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :country, :through => :user

  ..

end
```

So itemA.country yields "United States"

The question is how do I created a (named) scope for all items owned by US users

When I try something like:

```
scope :american, where('countries.name' => 'United States').includes([:user, :country])
```

then Item.american keeps coming back empty even when Item.first.country => 'United States'

Incidentally, in the Rails 2.3.4 version we had:

```
named_scope :american, :include => {:user, :country}, :conditions => { 'countries.printable_name' => 'United States' }
```

And that worked as advertised.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but you should update to Rails 3.0.4 as it's a security release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pluralize the table names, I also think the ordering of include and where may matter. It's also recommended to use a join instead when specifying conditions on associations like so:

```
scope :american, joins(:users, :countries).where('countries.name' => 'United States')
```

If you'd prefer to still use includes:

```
scope :american, includes(:users, :countries).where('countries.name' => 'United States')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with the following: scope :american, joins(:user, :country).where('countries.name' => 'United States') so I guess the table names don't need to be pluralized.

Comment: Arguments to the joins method should correspond with the association. So for belongs_to :user it would be joins(:user) and for has_many(:users) it would be joins(:users)